# Android Preference: CheckBoxPreference - Difference between defaultValue and checked

Tags: android, android-preferences, preference, checkboxpreference

In CheckBoxPreference, what is the difference between "android:defaultValue" and "android:checked"? Both seems to be doing the same thing

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_"
    android:title=""
    android:summary=""
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:checked="true">
</CheckBoxPreference>
```

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:defaultValue

Answer (score 0):

Sets the checked state and saves it to the SharedPreferences. And Sets the default value for this Preference, which will be set either if persistence is off or persistence is on and the preference is not found in the persistent storage.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. Can you rephrase it please?

Answer (score 0):

@andychen the default value tag defines what value should be fetched from preference if the user hasn't explicitly stored any value for checkbox in preference. And tag checked defines what state of checkbox should be shown to user on screen initialization